# Localization of remote notifications strings breaks device set language and zone settings Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I have started translating my app and it's the first time I do it but until now every thing just run smoothly, all user interface has easy being translated by just adding a new language, and translate values in the new `Main.strings (Italian)` as the one I'm on right now. My problem starts with  those `NSLocalizedString` I used for example in remote notifications. I don't get any error from Xcode but as soon as I add the translation for those to the `Main.strings (Italian)` file, than the interface on device goes back to English, if I comment out the translation it then goes the set language. Do I have to put translations for `NSLocalizedString` somewhere else or what am I doing wrong here ? I had a look at other posts and the solutions are pretty much as I'm doing things here.
As always many thanks.
This is how I'm doing it:

Remote notification:

```
PushNotifications.sendPushNotification(to: customerFcmToken, title: String(format: NSLocalizedString("Order number: %1@", comment: ""), orderId), subtitle: String(format: NSLocalizedString("Shop: %1@", comment: ""), UserDetails.fullName!),body: String(format: NSLocalizedString("Thank you %1@! We received your order and we'll let you know when we start preparing it and when it's ready. Bye", comment: ""), customerName))
```

translation in Main.strings (Italian)

```
"Order number: %1@" = "Ordine numero: %1@"
"Shop: %1@" = "Negozio: %1@"
"Thank you %1@! We received your order and we'll let you know when we start preparing it and when it's ready. Bye" = "Grazie %1@! Abbiamo ricevuto il tuo ordine e ti faremo sapere quando cominceremo la sua preparazione e quando sarà pronto per essere ritirato. Ciao."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
It actually had to do with the whole Localization set up, so I'll leave the correct steps for others struggling with it.

Before adding a new language:

1. Create a new String file from `addFile` command. Name it Localizable.
2. In properties inspector localise it choosing `English` from drop down menu. It doesn't show `(Base)`.
3. Now add a new language. It will now create localised files also for the `Localizable.string`file.
4. Add key/value pairs for all the `NSLocalizableString`you will use in your code. Do not miss `;`at the end of the line, if missing the file won't be readable.

So now the code is:

English :

```
// Order Revceived
"orderReceivedTitle" = "Order number: %1@";
"orderReceivedSubtitle" = "Shop: %1@";
"orderReceivedBody" = "Thank you %1@! We received your order and we'll let you know when we start preparing it and when it's ready. Bye";
```

Italian:

```
// Order Revceived
"orderReceivedTitle" = "Ordine numero: %1@";
"orderReceivedSubtitle" = "Negozio: %1@";
"orderReceivedBody" = "Grazie %1@! Abbiamo ricevuto il tuo ordine e ti faremo sapere quando cominceremo la sua preparazione e quando sarà pronto per essere ritirato. Ciao.";
```

Push notification:

```
PushNotifications.sendPushNotification(to: customerFcmToken, title: String(format: NSLocalizedString("orderReceivedTitle", comment: ""), orderId), subtitle: String(format: NSLocalizedString("orderdReceivedSubtitle", comment: ""), UserDetails.fullName!),body: String(format: NSLocalizedString("orderReceivedBody", comment: ""), customerName))
```

This will send a remote notification in the language the sending device is set to, and the receiving device will get it in that language.

Next step is to show the remote notification in the lagunage that the receiving device is set to.

For that the sent payload has to use `"loc-key"` and `"loc-args"` and have those in the `Localizable.string` files on the receiving device also as I use remote notifications on two related apps : Shop(sending) and Customer(receiving).
I will update the answer including that part of code as soon as I finish it.

Comment: Did you find the solution for localising remote notification ? @Vincenzo

Comment: @ArpitBParekh this is a very old question and I already provided the solution. What's not clear about it? I might be able to help further

Comment: I have set AppleLanguages user defaults to es (Spanish). I have set loc_key and args as u desribed in answer, stillwhen push comes from server it is not taking settings from Locliasable.strings